# Finding min and max of a given array in scala

Tags: arrays, scala, max, min, arraybuffer

I have an array as below. what I am trying to understand are min and max inbuilt functions.

```
val bf=Array("wheels","on","the","bus")
```

For Max, the output is "wheels" which is right because the number of elements for wheels is big compared to others
But when I try bf.min. I get the output as "bus". If min gives element with minimum elements then it should be "on"? am I right? what am I missing here? can someone please help me understand what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `"aaaaaaaa" < "b" && "bbbbbbbbbbb" < "c" & "ccccccc" < "d"`, [StringOrdering source code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.8/src/library/scala/math/Ordering.scala#L329)

Comment: Can you explain why you think "on" is lexicographically smaller than "bus"? At least in my language's alphabet "b" comes *before* "o", not after. In a lexicon in your native language, would the word "bus" come after the word "on"?

Comment: @JoergWMittag Thank you that's my doubt and so the reason of posting my question here. please read my question, I was confused it as the number of elements. Yes, in english language 'b' comes before 'o' and after 'a'. Thanks for enlightening me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alphanumeric order is used by default, when comparing strings.

You want to use minBy, maxBy if you want to get the shortest or longest string respectively.

```
bf.minBy(_.length)
```

[Array#maxBy](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array.html#maxBy[B](f:A=%3EB):A)

Answer (score 3):

`min` function uses Java String `compareTo` method to compare a Unicode value of each character in the strings.

If we compare `on` and `bus`, then `bus` will be smaller:

```
@ "on".compareTo("bus")
res16: Int = 13
```

`13` is difference of integer values of `o` and `b`. Also, return value is positive, which means left operant is greater than right operand.

and `on` is smaller than `wheels` and so on:

```
@ "on".compareTo("wheels")
res17: Int = -8
```

Here we have negative return value, which means left operand is smaller tha right operand.

See more information here: https://www.journaldev.com/18009/java-string-compare